# Hessian matrix of $\Lambda \mapsto y' (I + X\Lambda X')^{-1}y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix, kronecker-product

I have $$f=y'M^{-1}y$$ where $$M = I + X\Lambda X'$$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, and $\Lambda$ is a $p\times p$ symmetric positive-definite matrix. I'm trying to compute the Hessian matrix of this quadratic form with respect to the [half-vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Half-vectorization) $\mathrm{vech}(\Lambda)$, i.e., $$\partial^2 f/(\partial \mathrm{vech}(\Lambda)\partial \mathrm{vech}(\Lambda)')$$ Here's what I've got so far ($D_p$ is the $p^2\times \frac{1}{2}p(p+1)$ duplication matrix):

$$
        \begin{align}
            \mathsf{d}f &= -y'M^{-1}(\mathsf{d}M)M^{-1}y \\ &= -y'M^{-1}X(\mathsf{d}\Lambda)X'M^{-1}y \\\\
            &= -(y'M^{-1}X \otimes y'M^{-1}X)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}(\Lambda)\\\\
            &=-(y'M^{-1}X \otimes y'M^{-1}X)D_p\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vech}(\Lambda),\\\\
            \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathrm{vech}(\Lambda)'} &= -D_p'\left(X'M^{-1}y \otimes X'M^{-1}y \right).
        \end{align}
$$
Redefine $f = -D_p'\left(X'M^{-1}y \otimes X'M^{-1}y \right)$. Then,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathsf{d}f &= -D_p'\mathsf{d}\left(X'M^{-1}y \otimes X'M^{-1}y \right) \\\\
            &= D_p'\left\{X'M^{-1}(\mathsf{d}M)M^{-1}y\otimes X'M^{-1}y + X'M^{-1}y \otimes X'M^{-1}(\mathsf{d}M)M^{-1}y \right\}\\\\
            &= D_p'\left\{X'M^{-1}X(\mathsf{d}\Lambda)X'M^{-1}y \otimes X'M^{-1}y  + X'M^{-1}y \otimes X'M^{-1}X(\mathsf{d}\Lambda)X'M^{-1}y \right\}\\\\
            &= D_p'\left\{\left(y'M^{-1}X \otimes X'M^{-1}X \right)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}(\Lambda) \otimes X'M^{-1}y \right. \\\\
            &\left. + X'M^{-1}y \otimes \left(y'M^{-1}X' \otimes X'M^{-1}X \right)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}(\Lambda) \right\}.
\end{align}
$$
How do I take $\mathrm{vec}(\Lambda)$ out?

To simplify the question, how do I take $\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}(\Lambda)$ out of the following:
$$
\mathsf{d}f = \left[\left\{(A \otimes B)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}(\Lambda)\right\} \otimes C\right\}+\left\{C \otimes \left\{(A \otimes B)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}(\Lambda)\right\}\right]?
$$

### Update

Using [greg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/357854/greg)'s answer, I now have
$$
\begin{align}
X'M^{-1}y\otimes (y'M^{-1}X \otimes X'M^{-1}X)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}\Lambda &= (X'M^{-1}y\otimes I_p)(y'M^{-1}X \otimes X'M^{-1}X)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}\Lambda \\\\
&= (X'M^{-1}yy'M^{-1}X \otimes X'M^{-1}X)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}\Lambda,
\end{align}
$$
which involves a symmetric matrix, but
$$
\begin{align}
(y'M^{-1}X \otimes X'M^{-1}X)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}\Lambda \otimes X'M^{-1}y &= (I_p \otimes X'M^{-1}y)(y'M^{-1}X \otimes X'M^{-1}X)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}\Lambda,
\end{align}
$$
which I cannot simplify.

Comment: @DaeyoungLim A quadratic form is not vector-transpose-times-matrix-times-vector.  Rather, it is a polynomial in which all monomials have degree $2$.  These polynomials can be written in the form $\bf x^\top Q \, x$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo That's what I meant. It would be a quadratic form if it were a function of $y$, but my equation is a function of $\Lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\vech#1{\op{vech}\LR{#1}}
\def\size#1{\op{size}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Given the following matrix sizes
$$\eqalign{
m,n &= \size{A} \\
p,q &= \size{B} \\
}$$
The formulas for vectorizing their Kronecker products are
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(A\otimes B)
 &= \Big(I_n\otimes K_{q,m}\otimes I_p\Big)\,\Big({\rm vec}(A)\otimes I_q\otimes I_p\Big)\:{\rm vec}(B) \\
{\rm vec}(B\otimes A)
 &= \Big(I_q\otimes K_{n,p}\otimes I_m\Big)\,\Big(I_q\otimes I_p\otimes{\rm vec}(A)\Big)\:{\rm vec}(B) \\
}$$
where $K_{n,p}$ is a [Commutation Matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix#2) and $I_p$ is an identity matrix.

Your calculations up to this point look good, so I'm confident that you can take it from here.

### Update

In the case that $A,B$ are column vectors
$$\eqalign{
m,\o &= \size{a},\qquad p,\o &= \size{b} \\
}$$
the formulas simplify to
$$\eqalign{
\vecc{a\otimes b}
 &= \Big(a\otimes I_p\Big)\,b \\
{\rm vec}(b\otimes a)
 &= \Big(I_p\otimes a\Big)\,b \\
}$$
If $H$ is the Hessian wrt the `vec()` operation
and $K$ is the Hessian wrt the `vech()` operation,
then they are related by
$$K = D^THD$$
**Both** Hessians are symmetric (assuming the calculations were done correctly).

### Update 2

Here's how I would arrange the calculations.

First, introduce a convention which uses uppercase letters for matrix variables, lowercase for vectors, and Greek letters for scalars.

Second, introduce the extremely versatile Frobenius $(:)$ product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \;=\; \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
Third, define the following variables for typing convenience
$$\eqalign{
Y &= yy^T \\
A &= \Lambda &\qiq a = \vecc{A} \\
M &= I+XAX^T &\qiq dM = X\:dA\:X^T \\
W &= M^{-1}  &\qiq dW = -W\:dM\:W \\
F &= -X^TWX \\
G &= -X^T WYW X \\
H &= {G\otimes F + F\otimes G} \\
}$$
$\sf NB:$ Except for $X$, all of these matrix variables are symmetric.

Now calculate the gradient of the scalar function
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= Y:W \\
d\phi &= Y:dW \\
 &= -Y:\LR{WX\:dA\:X^TW} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \\
 &= -\LR{X^TWYWX}:dA \\
 &= G:dA \\
 &= g:da \\
\grad{\phi}{a} &= g \\
}$$
Then the Hessian
$$\eqalign{
g &= -\vecc{X^T\c{W}Y\c{W}X} \\
dg
 &= -\vecc{X^T\:\c{dW}\:YWX + X^TWY\:\c{dW}\:X} \\
 &= \vecc{X^T\c{WX\:dA\:X^TW}YWX + X^TWY\c{WX\:dA\:X^TW}X} \\
 &= \vecc{F\:\c{dA}\:G + G\:\c{dA}\:F} \\
 &= \LR{G\otimes F + F\otimes G}\c{da} \\
 &= H\:da \\
\grad{g}{a} &= H \\
}$$
The above gradient $(g)$ and Hessian $(H)$ were calculated
with respect to $\vecc{A}.\:$ Calculating the gradient $(q)$ and Hessian $(K)$ wrt $\vech{A}$ is a simple matter of multiplying by the Duplication matrix $(D)$
$$\eqalign{
b &= \vech{A} \qiq a = Db \\
d\phi &= g:da = g:\LR{D\:db} = \LR{D^Tg}:db \\
\grad{\phi}{b} &= D^Tg \;\doteq\; q \\
\\
dq &= D^Tdg = D^TH\:da = D^THD\:db \\
\grad{q}{b} &= D^THD \;\doteq\; K \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Magnus & Neudecker (Chapter 3.7) has $\mathrm{vec}(A \otimes B) = (I_n\otimes G)\mathrm{vec}A = (H\otimes I_p)\mathrm{vec}B$, where $G = (K_{qm}\otimes I_p)(I_m\otimes \mathrm{vec}B)$ and $H=(I_n\otimes K_{qm})(\mathrm{vec}A \otimes I_q)$. Is this what you meant? I don't see how they're equivalent.

Comment: Actually, I can see how they're equivalent, using $(AB)\otimes C = (A\otimes C)(B\otimes I)$.

Comment: I have one more question. Applying your formulas, I get something like $\mathsf{d}f = D_p'WD_p \mathsf{d}\mathrm{vech}(\Lambda)$ but $W$ is not symmetric. Am I correct to apply the second identification theorem and declare that the Hessian is $D_p'\frac{W+W'}{2}D_p$?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've updated my progress too—please see the update in my question. I'm still stuck on $(I_p \otimes X'M^{-1}y)(y'M^{-1}X \otimes X'M^{-1}X)$, since the dimensions don't match and it doesn't seem symmetric. I'm at my wit's end. Please help

Comment: You are amazing. I now realize that what I needed to use was $y \otimes x = \mathrm{vec}(xy^T)$. Your derivation is so neat and elegant—something I aspire to emulate.